# C++: Destroying lambda within himself

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int global = 9;
std::function<void()> functor;

int main()
{
    int* ptr = &global;
    functor = [ptr]
    {
        functor = nullptr;
        std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
    };

    functor();
}
```

Here is variable `ptr` captured by lambda, and during `functor()` call functor first deleted through `functor = nullptr` and then accesses `ptr`. I think that `ptr` was corrupted since it was a field of a deleted functor. All the compilers successfully performs that program without crashes and print "9", but I still doubt that this is not undefined behavior. Can someone confirm it?

Comment: @keith I don't think that's quite a duplicate. That question is about the deletion itself and this one seems to be focused on the lamba's captured `ptr`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347103/remove-self-from-the-container-in-the-lambda similar?

Comment: @Whatever: Yes, that's an exact duplication (a `std::function` is a container with maximum size 1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is indeed undefined.

Here is how you can confirm it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct S
{
    ~S() {std::cout << "~S()\n";}
};

std::function<void()> functor;

int main()
{
    functor = [s = S()]
    {
        functor = nullptr;
        std::cout << "End of lambda\n";
    };

    functor();
}
```

The code above prints (on GCC and Clang):

> ```
> ~S()
> ~S()
> ~S()
> End of lambda
> ```

The 3 destroyed instances are: one captured by the original lambda, one captured by a copy stored in `functor` and one captured by a temporary that `std::function::operator=(F &&)` for some reason [has to make](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator%3D).

Comment: Actually you see three destructors because function<T>::operator=(F&&) is implemented in terms of swap, which creates additional copy of lambda.
To verify this you can make f a local variable, and initialize it during declaration - you will see only 2 S destructors calls then.